# Perform add/subtract hour/min from date time in freemaker

Tags: freemarker

I am new to freemarker.

In freemarker, I would like to perform arithmetic expression on DateTime as follows:

```
${triggerTimestamp}-1h
```

But this is not working. Could anyone please help here?

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker doesn't do date/time arithmetic out of the box (as of 2.3.30 at least). It's expected that the data-model (context) contains the values that you actually want to display. One can implement some helper method in Java though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to explore converting the date into unix/epoch time. If you add `?long` to the end of the variable you'll convert the datetime into epoch time (which is in seconds) then do math and convert it back to a  date. Your example would be

```
${(triggerTimestamp?long - 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60)?number_to_datetime?string.iso}
```